# Explication sortir/ faire sortir

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Bonjour,
Quelle est la différence entre :
Je vais faire sortir les élèves à la récréation et je vais sortir les élèves à la récréation

Answer (score 2):

La première phrase signifie que la personne qui parle va demander aux élèves de sortir au moment de la récréation. C'est certainement la phrase à laquelle on s'attend.

La deuxième signifie que la personne va prendre les élèves et les mettre à l'extérieur. C'est une tournure très inhabituelle dans ce contexte. On l'emploie plutôt pour des choses ou des animaux :

> *On va sortir les poubelles.*
> *On va sortir les vaches de l'étable.* (*faire sortir* est aussi possible dans ce cas)

*Sortir <quelqu'un>* peut quand même se recontrer en français relâché, mais avec un sens différent :

> *On va sortir les cousines ce soir.* (C.-à-d. : On va aller avec elles au restaurant, au spectacle, en soirée, etc.)